# Mock 'window' object in Jasmine + Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function which I want to unit-test and into it I am comparing global objects `window` & `parent` as `const isEqual = (window === parent)`;

Which is the best way how to mock those objects in Angular/TypeScript?

One more idea is to get those objects through function parameters, but anyway it's not solving this problem because I need to mock global `window` object too if I am using `getSomeData(win: Window, parent: Window) { // ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went with this solution:

Create service which will inject `window` object.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GlobalObjectService {
  public getWindow(): Window {
    return window;
  }
}
```

And in tests it's looks like:

```
describe('TestService', () => {
  ...
  let globalObjectService: jasmine.SpyObj<GlobalObjectService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    globalObjectService = jasmine.createSpyObj('GlobalObjectService', ['getWindow']);
    ...
  });

  describe('#testFunc', () => {
    it('should test something', () => {
      globalObjectService.getWindow.and.returnValue({
        location: {
          href: 'window.location.href',
        },
      });
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: return value location is not enough, it needs about 190 more properties...the return value should be an object of type Window

Comment: With `returnValue` you can return whatever property you need to mock. In this current case, I needed to mock `location.href`, that's why I returned only it.

Comment: ok, but getWIndow is supposed to return an object of type Window. An object of type window has many mandatory properties, if you only set location, it will say that object window is missing 191 more properties.

Comment: one way would be to say let globalObjectService: any;